# What is the etymology of "Salt" in relation to password storage?

Tags: salt, terminology

Simple question:

When talking about appending a random string to a password before hashing in order to defend against dictionary attacks, we call it a salt. Why do we call it a salt?

Comment: I will suggest without proof that whoever named it was thinking of the idea of "adding a dash of salt for flavor" :)

Comment: You need to study the culture and the life style of person who first used this term. **Conclusion:**  this question has nothing to do with IS community.

Comment: The term was already used in [Morris and Thompson's 1978 paper “Password Security: A Case History”](https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/passwd.ps). They don't give a citation for it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to talk about salt and keep things simple, think about a pizza:

[image]

Because you can not expect a better answer from serious and smart people:

> Does anybody know the salt's etymology in this context? Rob.desbois
>   14:45, 5 June 2006 (UTC)
>
> Nope. But I expect it's connected to the concept of salting a site with something, as in mining fraud. I got curious about this long ago
>   and seem to remember the OED has an entry of some antiquity. ww 18:53,
>   5 June 2006 (UTC)
>
> I would guess salting the earth is the most likely source. The actual data is "spoiled" to make it more difficult for an adversary to
>   use. JRM · Talk 12:17, 1 July 2006 (UTC)
>
> Ah, nice suggestions you guys have. Here's the way I usually think of it: Salt is our most common spice. So I tend to think
>   of it as the salt "spices up" the password/key. Of course, then
>   perhaps it should be called "pepper" instead. But also, salt is a well
>   known flavour enhancer. That is, adding some salt to food makes the
>   other tastes in the food stronger. (I don't know why it works like
>   that, but it is a well known fact). And the salt in cryptography does
>   make the password/key stronger. So I think "salt" is an excellent word
>   for it in many ways. And it is a short word, easy to spell and
>   pronounce, easy to translate to all other languages and doesn't change
>   cultural meaning when translated. It's perfect! --David Göthberg
>   11:58, 25 October 2006 (UTC)
>
> Hmmm... I suspect we have here some folk etymology which is nearly always plausible -- else it wouldn't have been
>   proposed and paased around -- but is often off the actual mark. The
>   first point I'd make is that, to my sense of the language, salt isn't
>   a spice. Spices are exotic (or were exotic once), tend to be plant
>   products (shredded tree bark, for instance), are used in quite small
>   quantities, and are entirely optional, nuitritionally. Salt doesn't
>   meet any of those tests, but perhaps my sense of 'spice' is at
>   variance with that of other English speakers. I can burn water without
>   half trying, after all. I wonder if there is a similar distinction in
>   other languages; there appears not to be one such in Swedish
>   (Davidgothberg's native tongue if I understand correctly).
>
> My personal, completely unsubstantiated guess is that it comes from the phrase "take it with a grain of salt".
>   Tomfelker 23:22, 22 October 2007 (UTC)
>
> But I like the etymology/analogy whether folk or not. ww 14:06, 25 October 2006 (UTC)
>
> I've always presumed that the origin of "salt" is as a sort of back-analogy with the fact that you seed a PRNG=Pseudorandom number
>   generator. The bit of gibberish that you feed to PRNG is a seed
>   because it's the start of things and what it is determines everything
>   that then happens (what plant grows out of that pot depends on whether
>   the seed is a geranium seed or a sunflower seed.) So you try to
>   generate a bit of unpredictable gibberish as a seed. However, when you
>   generate a similar value, but if it is input not to a PRNG, but to a
>   hashing algorithm, you're not actually using as a seed to anything.
>   So, salt is a nicely similar-sounding word (phonologically: each
>   starts with an 's', has a double-mora syllabic nucleus, and ends in a
>   consonant that differs from the other only in voicedness, otherwise
>   just being alveolar stops)— and it has a sort of sense of "aptness"
>   that invites folk etymologies like we see here. Compare: "spice" in
>   "Hasty Pudding cipher: Encryption_and_decryption". --Sburke (talk)
>   12:11, 17 March 2013 (UTC)

([Talk:Salt(Cryptography)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk%3ASalt_%28cryptography%29#Etymology))

Answer (score -2):

Salt always goes well with Hash :)

In all honestly I don't think anyone has confirmed why we use the term "salt" but if you do a quick google search you can see what others have theorized.